# Tkinter window outside desktop

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I show a window created with Tkinter.Tk() outside visible screen? I need to make it much bigger than the desktop size, and show part of it defined by coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Tk.geometry` with desired width, height and negative position.

```
from Tkinter import * # from tkinter import * (In Python 3.x)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('3000x3000+-100+-100')
root.mainloop()
```

I tested this on Ubuntu 12.04 (gnome) and Window 7.
In Ubuntu, it work well.
In Windows, negative position works, but width, height higher than resolution ignored.

Comment: Thanks. That's too easy. I think I was confused by documentation about +100 and -100, I didn't think about setting +-100 :).

Comment: Be aware that window sizes and position offsets are best kept in the range -32768…32767 (i.e., signed short). There are key low-level data structures that have explicit restrictions in relation to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to insert a frame and resize that, eg: 
    `import tkinter as tk` 
 
    `root = tk.Tk()
 frame = Frame(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
 frame.pack()
 root.mainloop`

The size of your window will then be determined by the frame, although the answer already given works just fine too